# How can I access all users from database?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im using firebase database to save my coordinates.

this is how my database looks like:[image: firebase database]

I'm saving data by token:

```
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        if (token == null) return;
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(token);`
```

So I need to access coordinates and add marker to a map

I'm doing it in valueEventListener in onMapReady method:

```
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            double allLat = (double) dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue();
            double allLng = (double) dataSnapshot.child("lng").getValue();

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(allLat, allLng)).title("Пользователь"));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Не найдены пользователи", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

but it set me only my marker, how I can access all users from my database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop through your values, inside your `onDataChange()`:

```
for(DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
            //get your mulitple markers here
        }
```

Comment: I have looped my code, as you said, but it continue to show me only my location

Comment: `public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    double allLat = (double) dataSnapshot.child("lat").getValue();
                    double allLng = (double) dataSnapshot.child("lng").getValue();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(allLat, allLng)).title("Пользователь"));}
            }`